# Find $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\binom{n}{k}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

I would like to find $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\binom{n}{k}$.
I tried to write this as an integral but I can't find the result.

Comment: unluckily there is no simple closed form solution here...i guess you will need hypergeometric functions ^:(

Comment: I agree with the above. By the Binomial theorem we can write this as an integral $\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k } \frac{1}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k } \int_0^1x^{k-1}{\rm d}x = \int_0^1\frac{(1+x)^n-1}{x}{\rm d}x$ however evaluating this seems to require hypergeometrical functions.

Comment: @Winther Yeah that's where I got stuck too. Guess it's a problem within the question itself.

Comment: btw the identity we find $\sum_{n=1}^n{n\choose k} \frac{1}{k} = \int_1^2\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}{\rm d}x$ looks quite similar to $\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}{n\choose k}\frac{1}{k} = \int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}{\rm d}x = H_n$ for the harmonic number. The latter does not have a closed form either. The integral we find is mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalization_to_the_complex_plane) ($a=2$). Mathematica gives the results as `n HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1 - n}, {2, 2}, -1]` which is $n \, _3F_2(1,1,1-n;2,2;-1)$ in more standard notation.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k{n\choose k}x^k$$
We are interested in $f(1)$ and note that
$$ f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}x^{k-1}=\frac1x\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}x^{k}=\frac{(1+x)^n-1}{x}$$
so that
$$f(1)=f(0)+\int_0^1f'(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1 \frac{(1+x)^n-1}{x}\,\mathrm dx$$

Comment: but this integral isn't really simpler then the original sum, right?

Comment: Substitute $t = x+1$ in above and its easy to calculate the value then.

Comment: @maverick thanks for the hint, but i don't see how to obtain a result following this substitution

Comment: by the way, the integral representation enables us to give a nice asymptotic estimate for the sum: $S_n\sim \frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}$